# Error while installing QWT library

Tags: qt, ubuntu, installation, qwt

I m trying to install QWT library,I m using QT 5.2 on Ubuntu Operating System.I have used the following commands.

```
svn checkout svn://svn.code.sf.net/p/qwt/code/branches/qwt-6.1

qmake qwt.pro

make -j4
```

While I use the make -j4
 command I get the following error

Error: cd src/ && ( test -e Makefile || /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake /home/vegeta/Downloads/qwt-6.1.0/src/src.pro -o Makefile ) && make -f Makefile

Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: svg
make: *** [sub-src-make_first-ordered] Error 3

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the QT SVG module development files, i.e., for QT5 on Ubuntu 14.04:

```
    sudo apt-get install libqt5svg5-dev
```

then QWT will compile with the SVG module.

**EDIT**

And to answer your comment in the other response, to compile the designer module you need its development files. On Ubuntu 14.04 these are sort of inconsistently named...

```
    sudo apt-get install qttools5-dev
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like your version of Qt has been built without SVG support.

Now you have 2 options:

1) rebuild and install Qt with SVG support
2) disable SVG usage in Qwt ( see qwtconfig.pri )

Comment: I have disabled the SVG in Qwtconfig.pri ...Now I m getting this error.........cd designer/ && ( test -e Makefile || /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake /home/vegeta/qwt-6.1.0/designer/designer.pro -o Makefile ) && make -f Makefile 
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: designer

Comment: Then you try to build the Qwt designer plugin, but your version of Qt lacks support for designer plugins.